# Underlying distribution // Backing out from convolution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convolution

Let' define $G_i^L$ as the cdf of the *average* of L independent draws from another cdf $G_i$. Let's further assume that I know $G_i^L$ (and the corresponding pdf/pmf $g_i^L$). Is it now possible from here on to back out the cdf $G_i$ for *any* $G_i^L$ and for any $integer L\in [2,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that all the draws have the identical distribution, otherwise it is lack of information.

If the distribution is infinitely-divisible, then it will be easy as in such case the sample average will have the same family of distribution as each individual (just scaled), and you just need to manipulate the parameters accordingly.

In general it may not be easy. The following is a theoretical way to compute, but may only be computed numerically.

Denote $X_i$ be the individual draw, having the common CDF $G_X$ and $\displaystyle \bar{X} = \frac {1} {L} \sum_{i=1}^L X_i$ be the sample average which have the CDF $G_{\bar{X}}$

First we compute the characteristic function $\varphi_{\bar{X}}$ from the CDF $G_{\bar{X}}$ :

$$ \varphi_{\bar{X}}(t) = E[e^{it\bar{X}}] 
= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{itx}dG_{\bar{X}} (x)$$

On the other hand,

$$ \begin{align} \varphi_{\bar{X}}(t) &= E[e^{it\bar{X}}] \\
&= E\left[\exp\left\{it\frac {1} {L} \sum_{i=1}^L X_i\right\}\right] \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^L E\left[\exp\left\{i\frac {t} {L} X_i\right\}\right] \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^L \varphi_{X_i}\left(\frac {t} {L}\right) \\
&= \varphi_{X_1}\left(\frac {t} {L}\right) \\
\end{align} $$

So we have

$$ \varphi_{X_1}\left(\frac {t} {L}\right) = \varphi_{\bar{X}}(t)^{1/L}$$

Finally we need to invert the characteristic function to obtain the CDF:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae

and they are closely related to the (inverse) Fourier Transform.

The above integrals may not have a closed form so numerically computation maybe needed.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your comment. Let me make a further comment on my question: As you assumed implicitly, in my case the draws are indeed distributed identically. However, in my case, $$ \varphi_{X_1}\left(\frac {t} {L}\right) = \varphi_{\bar{X}}(t)^{1/L}$$ is not analytically solveable, because $G_i$ is a piecewise function with an 'uniform part'. What options would I have to solve my problem numerically? A further comment is very much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This is just a theoretical framework, in practice I have not done any numerical (inverse) Fourier transform before, so it is hard for me to tell / recommend which algorithm suit best in your case. But I have heard many and should be available in most statistical/mathematical software